# Title export options of DT::datatable using shiny app

Tags: r, shiny, datatable, dt

Given following shiny app:

```
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("DT")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$DT <- renderDataTable({
    mtcars %>% 
      datatable(.,extensions = 'Buttons',
                options = list(dom = 'Bfrtip',
                               exportOptions = list(header = ""),
                               buttons = c('copy', 'csv', 'excel', 'pdf')))
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

one can copy the full table in the clipboard using the buttons on the top left of the datatable.

But when pasting the content into excel, notepad, or whatever there is a header, which I want to remove.

[image]

I'm pretty sure that the header can be deleted or changed using sth. similar to `exportOptions = list(header = ""),`. But not suprisingly this is not working. Perhaps one can find or translate a solution from [here](https://datatables.net/extensions/buttons/examples/print/columns.html) to R/Shiny.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's the `title` option of the button:

```
library(shiny)
library(DT)

ui <- fluidPage(
  br(),
  DTOutput("DT")
)

server <- function(input, output) {

  output$DT <- renderDT({
    mtcars %>% 
      datatable(., extensions = 'Buttons',
                options = list(
                  dom = 'Bfrtip',
                  buttons = list(
                    list(
                      extend = "copy", 
                      text = "COPY", 
                      title = NULL
                    )
                  )
                )
      )
  })  
}

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```